# zsh alias with default argument, but also overridable

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh

I currently have a zsh alias setup like so.

```
alias e="subl"
```

This lets me `e somedir` to open up a directory in SublimeText.  or `e .` to open up the current directory.

However, I would like to be able set `.` to be the default argument, or I can optionally pass in another directory.

So `e` should expand to `subl .`

And `e somedir` should expand to `subl somedir`

How exactly does one set this up? Is an alias even what I need here?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I would use a function:

```
function e() {
    if [ "$1" != "" ]
    then
        subl $1
    else
        subl .
    fi
}
```

adding it to *.profile*

Comment: +1 for using a function. You can shorten it to: `e() { subl "${1:-.}"; }`

Comment: This works well but you lose the command completion.  Although in this case the default of completing file names isn't bad.